# 2 rows presented as 1

Tags: t-sql

This query gives me 2 rows but the result is presented a just 1 row. I dont understand why. I want the result as 2 rows.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM table AS S1
      INNER JOIN table AS S2
        ON S1.code = S2.code
 WHERE  S1.column1 IS NULL
   AND S2.column1 IS NOT NULL
```

Here is the ouptput that i am expecting:

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
ID    login    email         code    column1
--------------------------------------------
96    testid1  test-Email1   XPQR    NULL
97    testid1  test-Email1   XPQR    P
```

Comment: What do you mean by "presented," and are you really self-joining within a single table or is it two different tables?

Comment: presented = I mean the result of the query is output as row

Comment: yes, i am indeed self joining the table

Comment: You're linking any record in `Table` with itself. Hence there are two records in `Table` in database 1 whereas there's only one record in `Table` in database 2.

Comment: Can you show sample data and what this "one row" you expect is supposed to look like?

Comment: If each row is being joined to itself, how can `column1` be `NULL` and `NOT NULL` at the same time? EDIT: eh, unless `code` is not unique.

Comment: I modified question to show the 2 rows that should be output

Comment: You must have forgotten to show SAMPLE DATA.

Comment: I added the sample data to the question posted above. Instead of the EXPECTED OUTPUT shown above, I get the same results but when the 5 columns of the first row are displayed, then the second row above  starts on the same row and is displayed as the next 5 columns

Comment: No, you added expected results. What is the data in the source tables that is supposed to produce those results? Surely you don't want us to guess? If the output of the same query is different in your two databases, then my guess is: the data is different in your two databases. Have you looked at the data directly to see what differences there are? Or should we guess that too?

Comment: Please, no word problems. We can't decipher things like "5 columns of the first row." Show us source data and expected output. Do you *want* the results as two rows? And can you clarify that you are seeing this result in one database but not the other?

Comment: The source data has thousands of rows. I am not sure of how to show the source data in a way that is helpful. But the above 2 OUTPUT rows are representative. Yes, I want the result as 2 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a wild guess:

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS S1
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT *
        FROM table AS S2
        WHERE ( S2.code = S1.code )
          AND (  ( S1.column1 IS NULL  AND  S2.column1 IS NOT NULL ) 
              OR ( S2.column1 IS NULL  AND  S1.column1 IS NOT NULL )
              )
      ) ;
```

Comment: +1 thanks for adding the extra parens. Not really necessary in this case but in general I think it is a better practice and helps self-document the code.